# Django ImageField passing a callable to upload_to

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to pass a custom upload_to function to my models imageField but I'd like to define the function as a model function....is that possible?

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=self.get_image_path)
    ...

    def get_image_path(self, filename):
        ...
        return image_path
```

Now i know i can't reference it by 'self' since self doesn't exist at that point...is there a way to do this? If not - where is the best place to define that function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django FileField with upload_to determined at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190697/django-filefield-with-upload-to-determined-at-runtime)

Comment: Yeah, look at the link that Paulo mentions - it shows it clearly there (no `self.`, define the callable as a function in the models.py)

Comment: Looks like my answer is here after all:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190697/django-filefield-with-upload-to-determined-at-runtime

Answer (score 9):

So Just remove "@classmethod" and Secator's code will work.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    # Need to be defined before the field    
    def get_image_path(self, filename): 
        # 'self' will work, because Django is explicitly passing it.
        return filename

    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_path)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [staticmethod](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#staticmethod) decorator to define the `upload_to` inside of a class (as a static method). Hovever it has no real benefit over typical solution, which is defining the get_image_path before class definition [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190697/django-filefield-with-upload-to-determined-at-runtime)).

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    # Need to be defined before the field
    @classmethod       
    def get_image_path(cls, filename): 
        # 'self' will work, because Django is explicitly passing it.
        return filename

    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_path)
```

Comment: @Secator: I tried this in my own code but it's not actually calling the method-- for the file location, I'm getting "Currently: <classmethod object at 0x9bf4944>/o7pDX.jpg"

Comment: @Colleen, it's converting my staticmethod to a string too. Looks like the method has to be a direct attribute of the module (or of some module).

Comment: it works find if you just define `get_image_path` as a normal method without `@classmethod`

Comment: in a `@classmethod`, the first param should be the class not the object. To make it less confused, I think you should use `cls` instead of `self`