# django - upload file to a specific folder

Tags: django, file-upload

I have a userprofile that captures the username and the group the user is assigned to. I want the uploaded files to be saved under the group name folder. The folders already exit at the media root, the files shoud be routed to these folder

I solved the problem by the solution given. Now the username is shown as a dropdown list on the upload page. I want only the logged it username to be shown or exclude even showing it

models.py

```py
class uploadmeta(models.Model):

    path = models.ForeignKey(Metadataform, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    user_profile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, verbose_name='Username')


    tar_gif = models.FileField(upload_to=nice_user_folder_upload, verbose_name="Dataset") # validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['tar', 'zip'])]


    def __str__(self):
        return self.request.user.username
```

```py
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    Group= models.CharField(max_length=500, choices=Group_choices, default='Please Select')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

view.py

```py
def uploaddata(request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:

                if request.method == 'POST':

                        form = uploadmetaform(request.POST, request.FILES)
                        if form.is_valid():
                                form.save()

                                return redirect('file_list')
                else:
                        form = uploadmetaform()
                return render(request, 'uploaddata.html', {
                        'form': form
                })
        else:
                return render(request, 'home.html')
```

forms.py

```py
class uploadmetaform(forms.ModelForm):
        count = Metadataform.objects.all().latest('id').id #To know the id of latest object
        data  = Metadataform.objects.all().filter(id=count) #return the queryset with only latest object
        path  = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=data)

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(uploadmetaform, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            count = Metadataform.objects.all().latest('id').id
            data = Metadataform.objects.all().filter(id=count)
            self.fields['path'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=data)


        class Meta:
            model = uploadmeta
            fields = ['path', 'user_profile','tar_gif',]
```

Comment: Pretty sure the answer is in here somewhere https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/file-uploads/ but I'm not volunteering to try to disentangle it. Also look for the documentation of `FieldFile` (where `fieldfile =  model_instance.file_field`). It has save (to name)  and delete methods but AFAIR no `rename`. There is of course `os.rename` ...

Comment: This may be even more directly relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090650/django-imagefield-passing-a-callable-to-upload-to although it's about ImageField not FileField so may not generalize

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `upload_to` argument in the `FileField`.
It accept a string representing the path where you want to store the file or you can pass in a function which let you add more details.

More info from the doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to

You may need to add a foreign key form `uploadmeta` to `UserProfile` like :

```
user_profile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Then you can use the following

```
def nice_user_folder_upload(instance, filename):
    extension = filename.split(".")[-1]
    return (
        f"your_already_definied_folder/{instance.user_profile.group}/{file}.{extension}"
    )
```

Then use it in `uploadmeta` `FileField`
 `doc = models.FileField(upload_to=nice_user_folder_upload, verbose_name="Dataset")`

Comment: it depends ont what you want to achieve: 1 user_profile can have multiple uploadmeta and 1 upload meta is link to one userprofile => define the relation inside uploadmeta.

If it's the oposite put it inside userprofile.

Comment: i am getting this error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: use a Group with a capital as it is defined in you model

Comment: tried that first before i commented getting the same error

Comment: i have added the upload view and the form.py. which template do you want to see?

Comment: @ ben Boyer... thank you, works fine. the slash  was the prorblem after the f"/--- f"your_already_definied_folder/{instance.user_profile.group}/{file}.{extension}"

Comment: need another help. Now this user fetched as a foreign key is shown in the form as a dropdown list of all the users. Is is possible to show only the logged in currect user in the form

Comment: Hi, just create another question because it's not directly related to the question here.

Comment: i have opened another question for getting the username, could you please answer it