# Django - for-loop with variable field name

Tags: python, django, image, for-loop, django-forms

Recently I started experimenting with Python and Django. I like it, learned already a lot, but still a long way to go...

I made a model containing 5 image fields. Next to the model I also made a form to enter data and save it. So far so good.
Now I want to write another form to 'edit' the uploaded images, meaning:

1. upload new images
2. delete the 'old' images from the database

I wrote the code below that does the job for 1 image:

```
if form.is_valid():
            form_image = form.cleaned_data['image_1']
            try:
                details = Model.objects.get(pk=pk)
                if details.image_1 != form_image:
                    details.image_1.delete(save=False)
            except: pass # when new photo then we do nothing, normal case
            form.save()
```

But I am struggling with following problems:

1. How can this code be rewritten to update 5 image fields? Because in worst case one can edit all 5 image fields. I tried with a 'for loop' but never succeed. For example:

   ```
   image_list = [image_1, image_2, image_3, image_4, image_5]
   if form.is_valid():
       for image in image_list:
           form_image = form.cleaned_data[image]
           try:
               details = Model.objects.get(pk=pk)
               if details.image != form_image:
                   details.image.delete(save=False)
           except: pass # when new photo then we do nothing, normal case
           form.save()
   ```
2. Are there more intelligent ways to write this piece of logic. A problem that I have with this code is that it checks on the name of the image. And probably this goes wrong when I have multiple images with the same name...

Hopefully someone can give some feedback and point me again in the right direction.

Many thanks!

Kind Regards

Comment: Hi again, the naming issue is solved: I can make the image name unique, using this renaming technique: [Django FileField with upload_to determined at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190697/django-filefield-with-upload-to-determined-at-runtime). But still the first point remains: how to loop over different images? And is this piece of code 'intelligent' meaning, is this the best way to handle the image upload? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use strings:

```
image_list = ['image_1', 'image_2', 'image_3', 'image_4', 'image_5']

# or doing that dynamically as well:
image_list = ['image_%d' % i for i in xrange(1,6)]
```

Also, from your example, I am not sure where you are getting a unique `pk` value each time. But assume each loop should produce a different `details` object to compare to that specific image.

One thing to consider is that you should almost never do a blanket `try, except: pass`. It can easily mask errors that you didn't consider:

```
try:
    details = Model.objects.get(pk=pk)
    ...
# django models have a special exception type
# when they don't exist.
except Model.DoesNotExist: 
    pass
```

In order to dynamically use those string names as variable lookups, you just need to use `getattr`

```
for image_name in image_list:
    ...
    # equiv to: details.image_1, details.image_2, ...
    if getattr(details, image_name, None) != form_image:
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback jdi. The problem with the strings is that I can't use it for the `details.image`. In the code I actually want to loop with the same variable on two places: `form.cleaned_data['variable']` and `details.variable`. Is this possible somehow? Thanks!