# Uploading files to directory named by the value of a Foreign key field

Tags: python, django

I want my photos to be uploaded to a directory that has the same name as the album they are in. I tried `photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=album.title)` but I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/bli1/Development/Django/Boothie/portfolio/models.py", line 33, in <module>
    class Photo(models.Model):
  File "/Users/bli1/Development/Django/Boothie/portfolio/models.py", line 36, in Photo
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=album.title)
AttributeError: 'ForeignKey' object has no attribute 'title'
```

I understand the error but I'm not sure how to upload to a directory named with the value of `Album.title`.

```
class Album(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    # thumbnail = models.ImageField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def images(self):
        lst = [x.photo.title for x in self.photo_set.all()]
        return lst

class Photo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=album.title)
    # width = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    # height = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    upload = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    # thumbnail = models.ImageField()
```

Comment: Here's the answer you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190697/django-filefield-with-upload-to-determined-at-runtime

Comment: @dylrei just what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    .....
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_photo_path_function)
    .....

def upload_photo_path_function(instance, filename):
    path = os.path.join('files/', instance.album.title)
    return path
```