# Django - Get database alias from QuerySet

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I want to set a dynamic `upload_to` in the `ImageField` fields using a method. Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1190866/3541922):

```
def content_file_name(instance, filename):
    return '/'.join(['content', instance.database_alias, filename])

class Content(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=content_file_name)
```

## Update

I don't know if is this useful, but I'm using **Django 1.7.1**

I'm doing a test with the model above:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models


def content_file_name(instance, filename):
    print "INSTANCE(%s)" % instance._state.db
    return "/".join(instance._state.db, filename)


class Cliente(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Cliente"
        verbose_name_plural = "Clientes"

    Nombre = models.CharField("Nombre", max_length=50)
    Foto = models.ImageField(upload_to=content_file_name)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "Hello World"

    MY_FIELDS = ["Nombre", "Foto"]
```

I'm getting in terminal on form submit:

**Terminal**

```
INSTANCE(None)
[19/May/2015 21:19:55] "POST /default/clientes/new HTTP/1.1" 500 168242
```

---

Another option could be making an import and get the database alias, but I don't know where get this from yet.

Answer (score 0):

`instance._state.db` should return the database alias.

Comment: Maybe this work for another django version, but don't in django 1.7.1 or at least not with `ImageFields`

Answer (score 0):

In Django 2.2.14, you can access the database alias using instance.db

```
qryset_employee = Employees.objects.using('OrgChartDatabase')
print(qryset_employee.db) ## Prints 'OrgChartDatabase'
```